# Unix utilities (cat, grep, ls etc.) for Android?

Tags: file-management, files, dropbox, text-editor, productivity

I'm transitioning to *one* folder with many (txt-)files, adapting (letters instead of symbols, lowercase only, no spaces) [Merlin Manns txt-setup](http://www.43folders.com/2005/12/12/text-setup). With `cat`, `grep`, `head` and [other Unix-utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aUnix_text_processing_utilities), it's better than a folder structure.

I use this on Ubuntu, storing the files in my Dropbox-folder. I'd like to have the same functionality on Android, but have come up empty handed. They don't have to be the same tools, and if I can only cover *part* of the functionality, that's a great start.

How can I get this (or similar) functionality?

Answer (score 21):

*Busybox* is a single utility that contains the functionality of many of the basic Unix tools. It's used on most embedded-Linux systems instead of having separate executables for each utility, which wastes space owing to code duplication.

There are several Busybox installers available on Google Play, and one on F-Droid. Custom ROMs often have Busybox built-in.

In addition, `grep` and `cat` (and a few more) are already built into Android. Android has its own Busybox-like called *Toolbox*, but it's a lot smaller (i.e. more limited) than the full Busybox.

You can access Toolbox commands (or Busybox commands once you've installed it) from a terminal emulator, in just the same way as any Unix system.

Comment: +1. Busybox brings everything OP seems to want *and a **lot** more*.

Comment: Android `toolbox` is a small set of utilities taken from NetBSD, whereas BusyBox provides a lot of most-used "almost fully" functional programs.

Answer (score 1):

Busybox is not a full replacement. For example, i'm missing --binary-files in Busybox grep.

Alternatively, there's [GNU CoreUtils](https://www.xda-developers.com/busybox-replacement-on-the-horizon-meet-gnu-coreutils-on-android/) on XDA-Developers.

Comment: Go get [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) if you want full `grep` and something else.